# host controller is unable to connect to domain controller while setting up JBOSS cluster

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly-8

[Host Controller] 03:03:52,521 WARN  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS010900: Could not connect to remote domain controller at remote://172.16.2.135:9999 -- java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174: Could not connect to remote://172.16.2.135:9999. The connection failed

selinux is disabled on both hosts, iptables are stopped. Also, i am unable to telnet on port 9999. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We had exactly the same problem. Not only we were unable to telnet port 9999, but we also were unable to ping the other server. This is definitely a sign that the problem is in network configuration.
Check if there is a correct route to the other server. If not (sometimes the case of multiple servers at the same datacenter), add static routes to the other server (on both).

See this for more info with static routes: https://serverfault.com/questions/309628/force-static-route-for-ip-on-same-subnet